# OpenCV CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

Below is my code for the invisibility cloak, I am getting this error

`anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072875772 along with CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638

can anyone please help me with this code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

import time #for camera setup time

videoCap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #capture the video from 1st webcam

time.sleep(3) #2 sec for the camera to setup 

background = 0 #background that I have to display when I have the cloth on myself

for i in range(60): #30 iteration to capture the background
    ret, background = videoCap.read()

while(videoCap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = videoCap.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0, 120, 70])
    upper_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red) #seperating/segmenting the cloak part

    lower_red = np.array([170, 120, 70])
    upper_red = np.array([180, 255, 255])
    mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    mask1 = mask1 + mask2 # 1 or 2 i.e any shade of red between mask1 and mask2 then we need to segment that part

    mask1 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3,3), np.uint8), iterations=2) #noise Removal
    mask1 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask1, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((3,3), np.uint8), iterations=1)

    mask2 = cv2.bitwise_not(mask1) # mask2 == everything except the cloak

    res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(background, background, mask=mask1) #Used for segmentation of the color
    res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask2) #used to substitute the cloak part
    final_output = cv2.addWeighted(res1, 1, res2, 1, 0) #superimposing 2 images

    cv2.imshow('We did it !!', final_output)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break

    videoCap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

The captured problem here is Microsoft Media Foundation API's `MF_E_HW_MFT_FAILED_START_STREAMING`:

> A hardware device was unable to start streaming. This error code can be returned by a media source that represents a hardware device, such as a camera. For example, if the camera is already being used by another application, the method might return this error code.

This - in other words - means that the camera device is malfunctioning, the API is unable to start reading video frames. This low level error is then forwarded to you through OpenCV.

Comment: I'd start with checking if this camera is at all functioning, such as with regular Media Foundation software like Windows SDK topoedit, SDK samples or Windows Store Camera application. The code suggests that the camera is not okay overall, such as there is a problem with driver.

Comment: make sure the camera is avaiable.  If you have shared screen you need to make sure the laptop camera is visible

Answer (score 1):

old question, but i had similar in 2023.  MSMF is the culprit, not sure why but all the other tools work fine except OpenCV
My solution was to open using DSHOW instead

```
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```